# jqgrid works in chrome but not in IE

Tags: google-chrome, jqgrid, internet-explorer-7

i have been making a jqgrid. it works perfect in chrome but not at all in IE 7. please help !

i have to make this work in IE7 as my organisation does not support chrome yet !

(i tried to post my entire code but i couldn't because it was too much ! stackoverflow was asking me to add more details)

Comment: The goal of stackoverflow is not that somebody debugs your current long code. The goal is sharing of common problems which could help more as one person. So you should create small demo example which have **the same problem** which you have now, but which is small enough to be read by other visitors of stackoverflow.

Comment: oh thats all right, i just wanted to paste the code so that someone can test it and see the error themselves. i tried to paste a screenshot of the error that occurs when i try to load the grid in IE7 but i dont think i can paste images here. i'll try to create a small sample but i dont know which component of the grid is throwing IE7 off. it was working just fine last week but since then i have been using only google chrome for developing and adding more features as IE7 was slow. now when i run it, there is an error. i dont know which component of the grid is causing the problem.

Comment: You should have [privilege](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) to post images and many links in the text of the questions. The most important that you post JavaScript code and probably HTML code which describes what you do. You can easy [format the code](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189/147495) which you post. I don't think that without the code somebody can help you.

Comment: I can only guess that one from the possible problem can be fixed by including `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />` at the beginning of `<head>` your page (see [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:first_grid#html_file)).

Comment: thanks oleg, i tried adding those meta tags, but still there is the same error. it says 'Expected Identifier, string or number'. then it mentions some line number and character number. i know that the line and character numbers here do not correspond to the lines in jsp page.

Comment: you should include `jquery.jqGrid.src.js` instead of `jquery.jqGrid.min.js` in the project and post **the line number of error in `jquery.jqGrid.src.js`** (you should post which version of jqGrid exactly, like 4.5.2, you use). You can start Developer Tools (press F12), choose tab Script and click "Start Debugging". Do you verified that you have the same problem in IE8/IE9/IE10?

Comment: hi oleg, i included jquery.jqGrid.src.js instead of jquery.jqGrid.min.js but now the grid doesn't work show up in chrome either ! in IE 7 it shows an error saying Line:3768 Char 27 Error:'browser.msie' is null or not an object Code:0. when check jquery.jqGrid.src.js, there is no such thing there as browser.msie. i can see browser.msie at some other locations. also, after showing this error, the original error that it was displaying also pos up ! have you seen anything like this before ? i am using version 4.5.2 of jqgrid

Comment: Sorry, but the line `3768` of `jquery.jqGrid.src.js` version 4.5.2 don't contains `browser.msie`. If you search `jquery.jqGrid.src.js` for `browser.msie` you will find no such line. Do you started the code in debugger? I suppose that the error is *not* in jqGrid. I would recommend you to use more old version of [jQuery 1.8.3](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js).